# Is PDF/A-1b + accessibility equal to PDF/A-1a?

Tags: pdf, pdfa

we are creating accessible PDFs through our software. Currently, we are complaint with PDF/A-1b standard. Recently, we have started supporting accessibility also(compliant with Matterhorn Protocol). So can we now say our PDFs produced are PDF/A-1a compliant ? (assume all PDF/A-1b features are supported and new PDFs are PDF/UA compliant as per matterhorn protocol)

PS: I tried online PDF/A validators but they are not reliable. I am saying this because I tried their tools with PDF/A-1a compliant files (matterhorn reference PDF files) that are used as reference files by developer/testers, were also marked non-compliant by those tools.
So i am looking for a quick answer so that I don't have to go through long process of finding a reliable validator (plus that might be a paid software :) ).

Comment: I assume by "complaint" you actually mean "compliant"? I was very confused about the question until I made that substitution.

Comment: One requirement for PDF/A-1a is that the file itself claims to be PDF/A-1a compliant. If you have a PDF/A-1b compliant file plus some accessibility, the file still merely claims PDF/A-1b compliance, not A level compliance.

Comment: When the (online tools) mark them as non-compliant, they usually list exactly the points where they violate the standard, check these. When the only problem is that the doc "claims" only PDF/A-1a then this should be fixed.

Comment: @mkl: I am assuming you are talking about metadata information where we say this PDF has that comformance level under pdfaid tags. Is that what you are pointing at ?

Comment: *"pdfaid tags"* - Right, that's what I meant.

Comment: Nowadays i would use verapdf to valiate those files https://verapdf.org . Overall it seems to be more accurate than Callas pdf toolbox or Adobe Preflight to validate PDF/A (I am not connected to any of those companies).

Answer (score 0):

This question is confusing **PDF/A**, **PDF/UA**, and their intersection.

To clear things up, **PDF/A-1** refers to the **ISO 19005-1** specification from 2005, which places additional requirements and restrictions on the *PDF version 1.4* specification to make PDF documents suitable for long term archiving. **PDF/A-2** refers to the **ISO 19005-2** specification from 2011 which re-bases the PDF/A specification off of the **ISO 32000-1:2008** version of the *PDF v1.7* specification.

**PDF/UA-1** refers to the **ISO 14289-1** specification from 2012 which places additional requirements and restrictions on the **ISO 32000-1:2008** specification to make PDF documents *accessible* for assistive technology.

It is possible, but not necessarily easy, to make a PDF v1.7 document comply to both PDF/UA-1 and PDF/A-2 so that it is both accessible and ready for long-term archiving.

However, it is also possible to make a PDF/A document that can't ever conform to PDF/UA. PDF/A has *conformance levels* a and b (ignoring u) where the essential difference is that 'a' requires that a PDF document be tagged, while 'b' does not.

**Tagged PDF** is discussed in section *14.8* of the **ISO 32000-1:2008** PDF specification, it builds upon sections *14.6* (Marked Content) and *14.7* (Logical Structure).

Note that the following section (*14.9* Accessibility Support) is also of interest as the PDF/UA specification is all about accessibility and builds on top of all of these sections of the PDF specification: PDF/UA (among other requirements) essentially requires all content elements in a PDF to be tagged to be conformant.